# Stream events: finish vs end

Tags: gulp

How do I know which event to listen to?

For example `gulp.dest` fires the `finish` event and then somewhat later the `end` event. Some other streams only fire the `finish` event. When I have a method that returns a stream (could be a read or write stream) and I execute the method, how can I wait for the returned stream to be finished? When do I have to register for the `finish` and when for the `end` event?

Comment: I have the same question, I have noted that with remapIstanbul for example, my task was working using on('end') after remapIstanbul operator but now I had switch to on('finish') with lastest upgrade. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `gulp.dest` object is a Transform object - it handles reading from the (piped) source and writing to the destination. The 'end' event is emitted by the reader, while the 'finish' event is emitted by the writer.

If you are interested in ensuring the reading completes correctly, use `.on('end')`. See: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end.
Readable streams will emit this once data has been completely consumed by the stream. So there may be cases when it doesn't fire, due to the internal logic of the transformation or to an error condition.

If it is the completion of the writing you are interested in, then use `.on('finish')` instead. See: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish.
Writable streams will emit this after data has been flushed to the underlying system. So in cases where expected read errors are handled, or where the transformation ends the reading early, this event should still be fired. As I understand it, this won't fire if the *writing* fails unexpectedly.